# Sign-up page error popovers don't disappear when input boxes do

Tags: bug, status-completed

At https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup when I click "Signup" under "Sign up using Stack Exchange" and then click that title to minimize it, the popovers remain.

[image: Sign-up page with targetless popovers]

Comment: got a repro, fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in build `2014.11.18.2753` on meta and `2014.11.18.2020` on sites.

Comment: Nothing's changed for me, and I see "rev 2014.11.19.2761" in the footer.

Comment: @pvj should be working as expected as of the 2014.11.20.* build revisions